# eCommerce web-server that stores personal data remotely?

Tags: webserver, shopping-cart

I'm looking for an eCommerce web-server/cart solution that doesn't store personal data such as login, passwords, payment information locally. Instead it should store it a on a remote server that couldn't be accessed in case of a security breach.

I know it might be the wrong place to ask a such a question, but honestly I can't think of a better one.

Comment: If you know you're in the wrong place, why bother to ask? Downvote.

Comment: @MathiasMüller he said he *might* be in the wrong place. Either way, that doesn't make it a bad, or off-topic question. Upvote.

Comment: I agree, saying one might be in the wrong place does not make it off-topic of course. But asking for a tool, library or off-site resource does.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements [Stripe](http://stripe.com/) for payment information or [Moltin](https://molt.in) for cart/orders might be worth looking into. Not sure if these fit what exactly you are looking for though.